# Can i apply/bind custom filter with data-ng-model? Issue when binding custom filter with data-ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have defined custom filter to format input number to specific format i.e. hh:mm

**filter**

```
app.filter('formatDuration', function () {
    return function (duration) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(duration) || duration === null || duration.toString().trim() == '') return '';

        var hour = Math.floor(duration / 60);
        var min = duration % 60;
        if (min < 10) {
            min = '0' + min;
        }
        return hour + ':' + min;
    };
});
```

However, if i am unable to bind it with my `input type = text field data-ng-model = "myModel"`. 
When i enter something in input field's data-ng-model, it does not connect with my filter.

```
<input type="text" name="Duration" class="form-control" data-ng-model="{{Duration | formatDuration" />
```

But, if i bind it with value e.g. `value = "{{data-ng-model = Duration | formatDuration}}"` than it connects with my custom filter and do the required conversion but does not show formatted value inside input field instead shows what originally entered..

```
<input type="text" name="Duration" class="form-control" data-ng-model="Duration" value="{{Duration | formatDuration}}" />
```

So, i have few points to be clarified

**1)** Can i bind customer filter with data-ng-model? As per AngualrJs site Yes it should be
**2)** If so, than where i am wrong?

May be it is worth to mention that my input field is inside ng-repeat...

Comment: No, you can't. You need a $parser/$formatter combo. A filter is one-way: it can format a number to a duration string, but can't parse a duration string and make it a number. You need both for ng-model. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers

Comment: @ JB Nizet, could you share an example or working plnkr if possible? I never used $parser/$formatter combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you think about it... if you'd apply filter to your bound variable then it would be formatted when ever you type in something. Now if you type "1", you'd end up having formatted value of "0:01". Nice but this would then trigger filter again and you'd end up with "NaN:NaN".

You could use your custom filter and make it work by using e.g. `ng-blur` directive on your template, so filtering would only happen once.

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       ng-blur="formatDuration(duration)"
       data-ng-model="duration">
```

Where `formatDuration` would be fn

```
$scope.formatDuration = function(duration) {
  $scope.duration = $filter('formatDuration')(duration);
}
```

Comment: It is connecting with my filter. It converts 12 to 0:12 which is fine and assign this value to $scope.duration but in the input field it remains as 12. Remember in my case i have repeater so i am doing like this in html "<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       ng-blur="formatDuration(iteration.duration)"
       data-ng-model="iteration.duration">"  So, where i am going wrong?

Comment: @ Mikko Viitala, FYI: this solution will not work for me becuase i need to just show formatted value but when submit than send the original value.

Comment: Then you can't make it work with single ng-model and filter, if you don't convert the value back before sending or hold the original value in eg `iteration.$$duration` property and send that instead. But put up a plunker and I may give look at it.